# Leaflet change from JSON to CSV

Tags: leaflet, csv

Still to new to Leaflet but with small steps.... I will get somewhere.

I am loading now with jquery.getjson (and this works fine)

```
// Load the data
jQuery.getJSON("data/lieux_culture_nantes.json", function(data) {
    displayFeatures(data.features, layers, icons);
    var props = ['nom_comple', 'libcategor', 'commune'];
    fuseSearchCtrl.indexFeatures(data.features, props);
});
```

But for maintenance the user would like to use a CSV file

```
omnivore.csv('data/lieux_culture_nantes.csv').addTo(map);
```

But this does not shows the displayfeatures. Can someone give me some direction how to use the CSV option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSV parser from omnivore expects by default comma separated fields with headers. These headers should contains columns named `longitude` and `latitude`.

You may need to set the options to correctly read the CSV depending of the CSV source like below.

```js
omnivore.csv('data/lieux_culture_nantes.csv', {
  latfield: 'mylatitudefield',
  lonfield: 'mylongitudefield',
  delimiter: ';'
}).addTo(map);
```

A demo in action can be seen at https://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/963f269756daf33c4c1b5e786d5914a4